# gcloud builds submit command is not working as per the documentation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

Trying to build the image by using gcloud build submit command with passing the source as GCS bucket as per the syntax but it's not working.

gcloud builds submit  `gs://bucket/object.zip` --tag=gcr.io/my-project/image

Error : -bash: gs://bucket_name/build_files.zip: No such file or directory

This path exists in the GCP project where I'm executing the command but still it says no such file or directory.

What I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Build looks for local file or tar.gz file on Google Cloud Storage.

Is the case of a zip file like your case, the solution is to start to download locally the file, **UNZIP THE FILE** and then launch your Cloud Build.

Indeed, you need to unzip the file. Cloud Build won't do it for you, it can only ungzip and untar files. When you add --tag parameter, Cloud Build looks for a Dockerfile file if your set of file and run a docker build with this file.

Comment: As per the docs we can build the image with keeping source files (docker file) in the GCS bucket. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit                                         Trying to build the container image with remote source location because this is the way we can build the image using terraform with its remote execute feature.

Comment: Hmm yes, but read carefully: a tar.gz on Google Cloud storage. not a zip file. It's not the same thing, same encoding, same zip method.

Comment: tried with tar.gz file in GCS bucket still the same error. I guess documentation is not clear , its not helping to achieve what it says . If you have tried , please share the result / commands .

Answer (score 1):

Please try with single quotes(') or double quotes(") around  gs://bucket/object.zip, and not the back quote (`), so the command would look like this:
gcloud builds submit 'gs://bucket/object.zip' --tag=gcr.io/my-project/image

Looks like there is an issue with the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit), the changes have now been submitted to Google.

Comment: Tried with quotes as well no luck

Comment: What is the exact command that you are using? And are you still getting the same error? Also can you provide a screenshot of the error that you are facing in the question?